# Using Case Statement to show yes or no

Tags: ssms

I am writing a code that looks at a program where you can enter tasks for certain jobs. Basically, I want the code to look at the program, and if there is a task that includes "TCU" it would flag it as yes. If that particular job doesn't have a task with "TCU" then flag it no.

This is the code I have, but it is returning "No" for everything even though I know there are tasks for all of these jobs.

```sql
SELECT wip.FinalAssemblyJobNumber
    ,fa.SCHEDULE_GROUP_NAME
    ,wip.StabilityDate
    ,CASE 
        WHEN fs.Task = '%TCU%' 
        THEN 'YES' 
        ELSE 'NO' 
    END AS FS_Status
  
FROM FINAL_ASSEMBLY_WIP_VIEWER_037.dbo.FinalAssemblyWIP wip
    JOIN PIT.pub.FA_JOB fa ON fa.DISCRETE_JOB = wip.FinalAssemblyJobNumber
    LEFT JOIN FLOOR_SUPPORT_037.dbo.FloorSupport fs ON fs.JobNumber = fa.DISCRETE_JOB AND fs.Closed = 
    1 AND fs.Task LIKE '%TCU%'
    JOIN pit.mat.MTL_RQMTS AS mr ON mr.WIP_ENTITY_ID = fa.WIP_ENTITY_ID AND mr.ORGANIZATION_ID = 
    fa.ORGANIZATION_ID
    JOIN pit.pub.ITEM_ACTIVE AS ia ON ia.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = mr.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID AND 
    ia.ORGANIZATION_ID = mr.ORGANIZATION_ID
WHERE
    wip.Stage1Date < getdate()
    AND wip.StabilityDate IS NOT NULL
    AND wip.AuthorizedDate IS NULL
    AND ia.part_number = '991044688-'
    AND fs.JobNumber IS NULL
    AND wip.OracleCompletionDate IS NULL
ORDER BY wip.StabilityDate
```

Comment: In your `CASE WHEN` statement, you should use a `LIKE` instead of `=`, not sure if that will fix your problem though, but you can't use `=` on a `"%TCU%"` comparison

Answer (score 0):

In your `CASE WHEN` statement, you should use a `LIKE` instead of `=`, not sure if that will fix your problem though because your query is quite beefy, but you can't use `=` on a `"%TCU%"` comparison

Comment: I originally had Like but it still returned the same results